# Question on complete intersection ideal.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring with unity and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.

Suppose I want to know if $I$ is a complete intersection, I know that $I$ is finitely generated but I am unable to find its generators, how can I determine if $I$ is a complete intersection?

For example, I am thinking that there can be a relationship between $I$ being a complete intersection and the quotient ring $R/I$, like can we say $I$ is a complete intersection if and only if $R/I$ is....?

I am looking for more theory on this, any suggestions on papers and books are welcome.

Comment: Look at the book by Kunz at least for the case when $R$ is the polynomial ring.

Comment: @Mohan what book is that?

Comment: Introduction to commutative algebra and algebraic geometry, Birkhauser.